# How to pass query string into middleware function?

Tags: node.js, express

I need to pass query string into middleware function. Please help me thank you! Example `url: http://localhost/?somevariable=data`

```
middleware(variable,req,res,next){

  res.send(variable)

}

app.get('/',middleware(variable),(req,res)=>{
})
```

Edit: Why do you downvote me, this is a legitimate question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

querystring is stored in the req object, you don't need to pass it to middleware

```
middleware = (req, res, next) => {
    let query = req.query;
    console.log(query.somevariable); //data
    next();
}
```